# ugrading from TFS 2012 express Update 3 to TFS 2013 server edition

Tags: tfs

We are planning to upgrade from TFS 2012 express Update 3 to TFS 2013 server edition. Does anyone has any suggestion on how to do this or what steps should I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any specific issues with that upgrade path.  But here are some things that might help.

1. [Read over the TFS Planning and DR guide](https://vsarplanningguide.codeplex.com/)
2. Make sure your server meets the new [System requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578592.aspx)
3. Check out the upgrade documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj620933.aspx), and specifically "[Upgrade TFS Basic or Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj620928.aspx)"
4. Backup\Snapshot your TFS server before you start the upgrade.

Comment: No problem.  We recently upgraded 2012 server to 2013 and it was fairly straight forward, looking over that documentation there doesn't appear to be much more to upgrading express.

Comment: we are upgrading from Express to Server edition and I am worried about the DB side of it.